# Why is my Spring application run from my spring boot unit test

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a basic spring data application and I have written a unit test. What appears to happen is that when I run the Spring test my application run method gets called as well. I would like to know why this is and how to stop it please.

I have tried using active profiles but that doesnt fix the problem

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({ "com.demo" })
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private IncrementalLoadRepository repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

            IncrementalLoad incrementalLoad = new IncrementalLoad("fred", Instant.now(), Instant.now(), Instant.now());
            repo.save(incrementalLoad);
        }
```

and the unit test........

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    public class IncrementalLoadServiceTest {

        @Autowired
        private IncrementalLoadService incrementalLoadService;

        @Test
        public void checkInitialRecords_incrementalLoad() {
            List<IncrementalLoad> incrementalLoads = incrementalLoadService.list();
            assertEquals(3, incrementalLoads.size());
        }
```

Comment: See [this section of Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config) for an explanation of how Spring Boot resolves the context to use for testing. Essentially, you'll want a nested `@Configuration` class, or a separate `@SpringBootApplication` configuration to use for testing

Comment: thanks, yes creating another @SpringBootApplication worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I found the solution. I created another @SpringBootApplication class in my test folders. Initially that failed but I believe thats because the entity scan annotation pointed to packages where my "production" @SpringBootApplication was. I moved that class up a level and it all seems to work ok now.